# Adding a "lol" button

Tags: discussion, feature-request, fun

So, we were talking in the JS chatroom and we came linking the *noobiest* questions possible, questions you *can't* really answer...

For example :

- [Javascript Math Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715408/javascript-math-functions-for-jquery)
- [HTML <body onload=""> doesn't stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715062/html-body-onload-doesnt-stop)
- [how to change this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546251/how-to-change-this-code)
- [What does document.form mean in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715050/what-mean-document-form-in-javascript)

Because sometimes, we **need** it, a "lol" button near the "+1/-1" thingy would be great.

We should find ideas for what happen if we press the button though.

[Suggestion from @AndyE](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/254400#254400):

> x presses of the "lol" button results in your gravatar changing to a picture of a muppet.

Comment: I don't understand ... I keep on trying to retag this `always-friday-in-iceland` , but it no worky .... THE OUTRAGE

Comment: @waffles DESTROY THE HERETIC SYNONYM! SMITE IT WITH YOUR +2 BLESSED STAFF OF BURNINATION.

Comment: @waffles & @badp : Blame @YiJiang, he put the "fun" ;)

Answer (score 24):

Perhaps a 4 way voting arrow

[image]

Comment: Maybe with a custom-built, Stack Overflow-branded D-pad.

Comment: How is "lol" the opposite of "rofl"?

Comment: @badp: yeah, it should be "omgwtf".

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether it should be called `lol` or not, but it would be very helpful to mark questions as "dumb" or "googlable".

Right now there are a ton of questions where people just ask "How do I do X?", "What does function X of lib Y do?", although they could have found that out via some own research.

Now people might argue "SO is a site about Questions and Answers!". While that's definitely true, SO is not a replacement for people who don't know how to use Google or don't want to learn on their own or help them self. This might bring us some pretty repz, but does it really help the questioner in the long term? I don't think so.

If people are not forced to help them self, they simply won't do it. I can only speak for myself here, but learning how to help my self by reading through docs, FAQs or even the source code improved my skills by a lot.

Now, there are just a ton of questions every day that are hardly worth the effort of writing an answer to them; if it wasn't for the reputation.

Reputation should be a bonus, and not the reason to answer questions in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps a google icon that when clicked takes them to the google search with their question in the search.  The more people that press lol the bigger this google icon gets

Comment: Isn't that "close as duplicate"?

Comment: @Piskvor Most often there are no real duplicates for these questions, they are just extremely easy and haven't been asked yet.

Comment: Ho I like your idea @Tom Gullen. Make it an answer! not a comment!

Answer (score 3):

I support this wholeheartedly as a response along the lines of "mu", "unask the question", or "that's not even wrong".